# awk/grep print WHOLE record in file2 based on matched string list in file1

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

This question has some popularity on stackoverflow. I've looked through previous posts but can't quite get the solution I need.

I have two files. One file is a list of string identfiers, the other is a list of entries. I'd like to match each item in the list of file1 with an entry in file2, then print the whole matching record in file2.  My current issue is that I'm only able to print the first line (not whole record) of file two.

Examples:

```
File1
id100
id000
id004
...

File2
>gnl|gene42342|rna3234| id0023
CCAATGAGA
>gnl|gene402|rna9502| id004
AAAAAAGGGGGGGGGG
>gnl|gene422|rna22229| id100
GATTACAGATTACA
....
```

Desired output:

```
>gnl|gene402|rna9502| id004
AAAAAAGGGGGGGGGG
>gnl|gene422|rna22229| id100
GATTACAGATTACA
```

My current code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(index($0,i)){print $1 ;next}}' file1 file2
```

only prints:

```
>gnl|gene402|rna9502| id004
>gnl|gene422|rna22229| id100
```

and trying to specify the RS makes the entire file print..., ie:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(index($0,i)){RS=">"}{print $1 ;next}}' file1 file2
```

prints

```
>gnl|gene42342|rna3234| id0023
CCAATGAGA
>gnl|gene402|rna9502| id004
AAAAAAGGGGGGGGGG
>gnl|gene422|rna22229| id100
GATTACAGATTACA
....
```

I'm having the same issue with `grep`. First line prints, but not the entire record:

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

gives

```
>gnl|gene402|rna9502| id004
>gnl|gene422|rna22229| id100
```

I feel like I'm just defining the RS in the wrong place, but I can't figure out where.  Any advice is welcome!

edit:

real-life file looks more like this:

```
awk '{print $0}' file2

>gnl|gene49202|rna95089| id0023
GGTGCTCTAGACAAAACATTGATTCCTCGTGACTGGGATTAGCCAATAGCTGAACGCGACTGAGTGTGAAACACGGAGGA
GGAGTAGGAAGTTGGAACTAGACAGGCGACTCGGTTAGGGGACACCGGAGAGATGACTCATGACTCGTGGAAACCAACGT
GAGCTTGCCCGACAAAAGAATATGAAGAAAAGTCAGGATAAACAAAAGAAACAAGATGATGGCTTGTCTGCTGCTGCACG
GAAGCACTGACCCTTTCACCAAACCACAGTGCTCTCACTGCTATGTACTGTGTTCAGcctttttatttgtcacaggCTTGTAGCAT
AGCTCCTTTATTGCCTCTTGTACATACTATAAATTCTCCATATGATTCTCTTTATTTTCATCTATTCCCCACTGATGGCT
CTCTAACTGCATGCTGGTTTAGCATTGCTTAAGTCTGCTCTGGAAAATACATGTTTTGAGGGAGTACAAACAGATCATGT
CCCTTCCTTCAACTCAAATGACCTTTTTGTATTCACGGTGACCCAGttgaatatttaataaagaatttttttctgtga

>gnl|gene37771|rna78596| id230400
GGCGATACTAGATGTTGGCGGGGTTACACTGTAGATGCGGGGGGGCTACACTAGATGTGGGCGAGGCTACACTGCAGATG
TGGGCAAGGCTATACTAGATGTGGGTGGGGCTACACTGTAGATGTGGGTGGGGCTACACTTCAGATGTGGGCGAGGCTAT
ACTGTAGATGTGGGCTGAATTTCCTATAAAGCCTGTACCTTCTTTGTTTTTGCAGGGCTTGATGGCAGAATGGAGCAGCC
AGAGCTACAGAGTGGATGACCCAGATTTGGCCCTAACCTTTCCCACCCGGCCTGGTTTCCGTAGCTTTCCCAGTCCCCAA
GTCTTTCCTATTTTCTCCCTCTTGCCACAATCTGATCCCTGCAGTAACAATGAGCTGGTTGAGTAAACTTAACCCTCGGG
GAGCTGGCGGCAGGGCCAAGTGTCAGTCTCCAACCGCCGCTCACTGCC
```

Comment: Hi, you might be interested in using an awk derivation called [bioawk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) which seems to be able to understand these fasta-file formats.

Comment: this is very intriguing news... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As OP changed the Input_file so as per new Input I am writing this code now.

```
awk -F"| " 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} /^>/{flag=""} ($NF in a){flag=1} flag' FILE1  FILE2
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($3 in a){print $0;getline;print}' Input_file1 FS="|" Input_file2
```

Comment: No luck but thanks! Nothing prints. Possibly bc in the real file the second entries(ie: AAGGAGAG) are much longer, spanning multiple lines? Also a is not always guaranteed to be in 3rd column

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this should work if your records are separated by one or more empty lines.

```
$ awk -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file1 RS= file2
```

here the output is also separated with one empty line, if you want to remove the empty lines just delete `-v ORS='\n\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -A1 -Fwf file1 file2
>gnl|gene402|rna9502| id004
AAAAAAGGGGGGGGGG
>gnl|gene422|rna22229| id100
GATTACAGATTACA
```

The `-A1` means "also show **1** line **A**fter the match". Check your grep man page.

If the trailing information is a fixed number of lines, then adjust "1" accordingly. Otherwise you'll need awk or perl or ... for a more flexible solution.